# Refresh expiration of cookie of session in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, session, cookies, session-cookies, spring-session

I am solving problem with cookie expiration which holds information about session with given user.

I tried this solution:

[refresh cookie on each request in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549436/refresh-cookie-on-each-request-in-spring)

but condition `cookie.getValue().contentEquals(request.getSession().getId())` never pass

Our case: We have stored user session in redis, which has some expiration (for instance 30 min)

In spring we have configured cookie like this:

```
spring.session.timeout=1d
server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=1d
```

When user is working on website, session's expiration is renewed, but cookie has fixed expiration 1d, so in some moment remove all user data. We need set this cookie expiration by session, or automatically renew it. Is it possible? We are using boot 2.

Answer (score 1):

By default every cookie acts as a session cookie which means cookie is expired as soon as the session ends(basically when the browser is closed). But you are overriding the default behaviour and making it a permanent cookie by adding **server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=1d** Remove that property and it should work